# Redux does not call actions properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

In my React Native app I have redux actions to load and play a video. Whenever a user plays a video, the following will be executed:

```
this.props.dispatch(loadVideo(true, mediaID))
```

And the corresponding actions:

```
export const loadVideo = (isLoading, videoId) => async dispatch => {

   dispatch({
       type: LOAD_MEDIA,
       payload: isLoading
   })

   if(videoId){
      dispatch(playVideo(videoId))
   }
}


export const playVideo = (videoId) => async dispatch => {
    let p = await obtainMediaSource(videoId);

    dispatch({
       type: PLAY_MEDIA,
       payload: p
   })
   dispatch(loadVideo(false))
}
```

The problem is that somehow `loadVideo` action is waiting for `playVideo` action to finish executing before updating the state. However, I wish that `loadVideo` immediately updates the state to notify the app that a video is about to be loaded. What am I doing wrong here? Isn't this a good way to call actions (one calls the other)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good scenario to make use of `.then()` rather than `await`.

This way, you'll have a non-blocking function and capitalize on the callback to asynchronously dispatch `PLAY_MEDIA` once the media source has been fully obtained.

Here's an untested refactored code:

```
export const setLoading = (isLoading) => dispatch => {
   dispatch({
       type: LOAD_MEDIA,
       payload: isLoading
   })
}

export const loadVideo = (videoId) => dispatch => {

   if (!videoId) return;

   setLoading(true);

   // non-blocking
   obtainMediaSource(videoId)
     .then((p) => {
       dispatch({
         type: PLAY_MEDIA,
         payload: p
       })
       setLoading(false);
     });
}
```